# Error: function Error() { [native code] } at Object.r.trackException (https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js:1:83928)

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-application-insights

I am facing an issue while login into my application like

```
 Error: function Error() { [native code] }
    at Object.r.trackException (https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js:1:83928).
```

I didn't understood from where it was coming. while login there have a 3 razor html pages and AppInsights configured for application. i want to know it is the issue in application insight or frontend html pages or azure service fabric related issue. please help me.

Comment: `https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js` this is indeed an Azure Application Insights Javascript SDK. To further offer you help, please give us more detailed info such as how you set up Appinsights script 
and what custom code you have written to call into AppInsights script.

Comment: I was followed  the following link to setup AppInsights 
        https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-appinsights.                                                 
So, I am using AppInsightsService to get the Instance Of AppInsight.
now i written custom exception to trace exception in AppInsight in Azure.
like   
 this.appinsightsService.trackException(new Error('Exception In Class A methodB() Of Object:  ' + e.message));